# Why dont people in foreign countries buy bitcoins directly from USA

Tags: united-states, india, wire-transfer, cryptocurrency

I had a query related to buying and selling bitcoins from a foreign country like India where bitcoins can be bought locally now. I was wondering why people in India buy bitcoins locally through the bitcoin exchanges like unicoin as opposed to directly buying it from USA online ? Are there any benefits in doing so ?

Comment: Don't US bitcoin exchanges deal in US dollars? Dealing in local currency seems like a benefit to buying from a local exchange.

Comment: What do you mean "directly" from USA? Bitcoins are non-geographic dependent. They are not an official US currency, and they are 'mined' everywhere around the world. Perhaps some vendors who act as brokers give better/worse transactional fees than others, and perhaps unicoin / other Indian vendors offer particularly bad fees, but that is not self-evident from the way bitcoin is set up.

Answer (score 3):

Bitcoins from the USA will be sold in US dollars.  Purchasing them from any other country will involve currency conversion fees, however the payment is made.

If Bitcoins are available in the local country, they may well be cheaper as there will be no conversion fees to pay.